# Plot-save-close a histogram in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a data frame and wish to plot-save-close the histogram.

These are the codes:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create data
data = {'Marks': [22, 87,  5, 43, 56,
                  73, 55, 54, 11, 20,
                  51,  5, 79, 31, 27]}



#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


#create histogram and save the image
fig_verify = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
df.hist(grid=False, edgecolor='blue', bins=100)
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(1)
plt.close()
fig_verify.savefig("hist.png")
```

Here I see that the file created "hist.png" is blank.

Also, an another plot window appears which dosent close.

Can somebody please help me out with these two things:

1. Save the hist plot.
2. Close the hist plot.

Comment: You need to save before `plt.show()`.  Also note that `block=False` only works in a limited number of code environments. `plt.show()` usually clears the plot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to show the figure at all if you only want to save it.

You can simply:

```
fig = ...
fig.savefig("file.png")
plt.close(fig)
```